# php web service with json

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services

I am new to PHP & JSON, and based on a tutorial I made a simple web service which returns the contents of a table of a mysql db.

The output is in JSON and the database caracter set is UTF-8. my problem is that when I try to run this it throws me a 404 error, and doesn't show me where the error is. Any idea what might be wrong?

The PHP file is the following:

```
<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $link = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) or die("cannot connect to the DB");
  mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$link);
  $query = "select...";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error "));
  $num=mysql_numrows($result);
  $rows=array();
  while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $rows[]=$r;
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Any Idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: A 404 error means that the server couldn't find the page you requested. Make sure your URL is right.

Comment: If you replace all the PHP with "Hello, World!" do you still get the 404?

Comment: The pattern you're using is really old and prone to error. Please **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in new applications. This is a legacy interface from the 1990s that is in the process of being retired because of the hazards involved in using it incorrectly, something all too easy to do. It's best to use either `mysqli` or PDO in new projects, and [it's not even that hard](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Refer my web service code : Hope it will help you.
 [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702128/json-parsing-in-iosphp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following line before `json_encode()`

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this , I have written my php web service code.
follow this.
hope it will help you.

link  :

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702128/json-parsing-in-iosphp`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want use JSON? You can also use SOAP-NuSOAP and WSDL for creating a web service.  See, for example,
[Create a PHP Web Service in 5 Minutes Using PHP SOAP and WSDL Technology and NuSOAP](http://greatgandhi.wordpress.com/2009/11/25/create-a-php-webservice-in-5min-using-php-soap-and-wsdl-technology-nusoap/).

Comment: Please use English. This is atrocious. It also has nothing to do with the question. I'd also downvote you again if I could for even suggesting SOAP, something that has caused many a developer to go bald from pulling their hair out.

Comment: my friend do you read question completely?he is new to php and can start from soap and nusoap to understand form of webservices .....