# json parsing in ios+php

Tags: php, ios, json, web-services, function

I have created web service in PHP which is having 1 function with 1 parameter.
   I am using phpMyadmin as back end.
   It is using json format for fetching data.
   Web service is working perfectly.
   I want to use this web service in my iPhone app.
   I want to pass 1 parameter.
   I have referred rayWenderlich tutorial also as reference.
   But can not find the solution.
   Please help me out.

This is my web service code:

```
<?php

echo getdata($_REQUEST['lastupdate']);

function getdata($lastupdatedate){

    $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';       
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    //print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345    

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","un","Password");          

    if (!$con){
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //print_r($con);            
    mysql_select_db("roster", $con);

    $query = "select * from rates where LastUpdated = '".$lastupdatedate."' order by LastUpdated limit 1";    
    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die($query);

    //print_r($rs);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){    
        $record[] = $row;    
    }
    $data = json_encode($record);

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');    
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');    
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    return $data;    
}
```

Iphone App side , I have tried below code:

```
-(void)GETJSONDATA
{
    SBJSON *json = [SBJSON new];
    json.humanReadable = YES;
    responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *service = @"";
    NSString *str;
    str = @"LastUpdated";


    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"LastUpdated\":\"%@\"}",str];

    // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKey:@"WRONGANSWER"];

    NSLog(@"request string:%@",requestString);
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];


    NSString *fileLoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"URLName" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *fileContents = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLoc];
    NSString *urlLoc = [fileContents objectForKey:@"URL"];
    urlLoc = [urlLoc stringByAppendingString:@"?lastupdate=2012-09-01 01:00:00"];
    NSLog(@"URL : %@",urlLoc);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: 
                                    [NSURL URLWithString: urlLoc]];  
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    NSError *respError = nil;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: &respError ];


    if (respError) 
    {
        //        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
        //                         [respError localizedDescription],
        //                         [[respError userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]]; 
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ACTEC" 
                                                            message:@"check your network connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];


    } 
    else
    {
        NSUserDefaults *dd = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Resp : %@",responseString);

        NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
        NSLog(@"results=%@",results);

}
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but where are you having issues? You said the service is working...

Comment: ya.But I don't know from ios side..that how should I give url ,how should I pass function , take input as parameter and all...I am editing my question in which i am giving my trial code.

Comment: Any reason you're making that a function, instead of just a PHP page?

Comment: ya..I need to pass 1 parameter in my function

Comment: All I'm saying is that you didn't need to explicitly create a PHP function for this... You could have just made a PHP page... If you're taking the approach of using functions, you should be extracting and creating more than one function so that the code is more readable. May even want to create a class out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using a library. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) provides a class called AFHTTPClient that allows you to connect to a restful web service and make simple calls to it. Assuming an end point, you can do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *body = [NSDictionary dictionaryWitObject:@"LastUpdated" forKey:@"LastUpdated"];

NSString *fileLoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"URLName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *fileContents = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLoc];
NSString *urlLoc = [fileContents objectForKey:@"URL"];
urlLoc = [urlLoc stringByAppendingString:@"?lastupdate=2012-09-01 01:00:00"];    

AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLoc]];

[client postPath:@"endpoint" parameters:body success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Do something with the responseObject

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Log the error and proceed

}];
```

You can find the docs here: http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html

Comment: Sir network connection is correct in my code . But I don't know how to pass function and what should I give as url and how can i manage 1 input parameter : my link is this : http://domain/ACTEC_WebService.php?lastupdate=2012-09-01 01:00:00     please can you give solution according to my mentioned code?